# Can not add cordova platform on cordova 7.1.0: Path must be a string

Tags: cordova, path

I have got a problem using cordova. After updating cordova I receive "Error: Path must be a string! Received undefined" I thought it might be some issue of platform configuration so I removed the android platform and tried to add it again. Same error. I have updated all installed plugins and the android SDK. For a last chance I tried to add iOS platform and received same error.

Before update all things were ok and the application was build successfully.

```
Cordova version 7.1.0

cordova platform list
Installed platforms:
  android 6.3.0


cordova plugin list
com.makina.offline.mbtiles 1.0.0 "MBTilesPlugin"
com.megster.cordova.FileChooser 0.0.0 "File Chooser"
com.phonegap.plugins.nativesettingsopener 1.2 "Native settings"
cordova-plugin-advanced-geolocation 1.1.0 "Cordova Advanced Geolocation Plugin - Android"
cordova-plugin-appversion 1.0.0 "App Version"
cordova-plugin-background-mode 0.7.2 "BackgroundMode"
cordova-plugin-battery-status 1.2.4 "Battery"
cordova-plugin-buildinfo 1.1.0 "BuildInfo"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.3 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.3 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-filepath 1.0.2 "FilePath"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.3 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-sqlite 1.0.3 "Cordova Sqllite Plugine"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-vibration 2.1.5 "Vibration"
```

I have found a lot of issues sounding quite similar but did not find any solution since most said "deleted and reinstalled platform and worked".

Do you have any ideas about it? 
Best regards and thanks!

Comment: You should revert to `7.0.1` it should be fixed in `7.1.1`

Comment: I have tried earlier versions resulting in several other errors... I'll try your solution the next days... (if 7.1.1 is not already available...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this happened the same thing, after the update, I made several attempts to solve this problem, and in the end, for me, what solved was to remove from my config.xml the "config-file" tags that I had to manipulate some specific properties inside of the * -Info.plist files

After I checked out it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks! Would have never guessed but it worked for me!

Comment: and how did you define the configs? i am using phonegap cloud build and need this configurations - and I cannot change the plist files;)

Answer (score 0):

For some interest: I tried several ways to figure out which string is meant. In the end, I have created a new application in cordova cli and copied all plugins and www-data into it. At this point, the app compiled - but did not allow any connection to external sources (e.g. server for map data). For this, I updated the cordova-plugin-whitelist, which caused the new app to stop compiling with the same issue as mentioned in the question.

Combining the solution of Marcelo with an update of the whitelist plugin fixed the issue.